# Please explain Python's "pass-by-pointer" approach

Tags: python, variables, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
a = 5
```

a is not holding the value 5 itself but only an address to the object 5, correct? So it is a reference variable.

```
b = a
```

Now it seems to me that `b`, instead of again holding the address of `a`, is actually holding the `"value"` of a, which was the address of the object 5. Isn't this the result of Python being pass-by-value?

But how should I understand this apparent discrepancy?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you tell the difference between `b` referencing `5` and `b` holding a copy of `5`? It's not like `5` is mutable.

Comment: because in python 5 is an object and variables don't "store" objects they just "refer" to them. b = 5 means b is neither holding a copy of 5 nor 5 itself rather that b now refers to the object 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no discrepancy.

Think of the assignment `a=5` as putting a labelled tag 'a' around 5.

Now if you set `b=a`, python looks what is labelled `a` (5) and attaches a new label `b` to it.

Assignment operators never reference the *name* of a variable. They always chase the reference down and then reference the chased-down **value**.

In truth, it doesn't quite work the way I described, because for simple data types such as ints, there isn't just a single copy of the 5 in memory. But you can *act* as if it worked like that, and won't ever get surprised.

It's easier to understand if you use lists instead of a simple integer:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
```

There is only a single list in existence, and both `a` and `b` now reference it, which explains the following.

```
>>> b[0] = 5
>>> a
[5, 2, 3]
```

Comment: For small enough integers to be automatically interned, there *is* often only a single copy in memory. Which is to say that for the specific example in use, the oversimplification may work. :)

Comment: Yes I've heared the same. I was somewhat confused that Pascal said this was a oversimplification. Thanks :)